# modifying columns of pandas data-frame on different conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is my data-frame and I want to convert the values in column c and d into KB.
Here M stands for Mega-byte and G stands for Gigabyte. How it can be done.

```
               b         c         d
              abc      12.8G     12.6G
              def      2.67M      3.4G
              ghi      12.5G     34.5M
              jkl      12.1G      1.2G
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dict mapping with `.str` accessor will help i.e

```
di = {'M':10**3,'G':10**6 }

df[['c','d']] = df[['c','d']].apply(lambda x : pd.to_numeric(x.str[:-1]) * x.str[-1].map(di)).astype(str) + 'KB'
```

```
     b             c             d
0  abc  12800000.0KB  12600000.0KB
1  def      2670.0KB   3400000.0KB
2  ghi  12500000.0KB     34500.0KB
3  jkl  12100000.0KB   1200000.0KB
```

If you need just the integer then use

```
df[['c','d']].apply(lambda x : pd.to_numeric(x.str[:-1]) * x.str[-1].map(di)).astype(int)
```

Comment: and if we want just the integer part!!

Comment: You need only the integer?

Comment: yeah i only need integer part

Comment: and what if it the columns (c and d) consists of zeroes also.

Comment: or NAN values also

Comment: Its not good to ask what ifs before trying. Try once and report if you face any errors ;).

Comment: I have tried it with NA values it is giving error. i firstly have used following command ......df = df.fillna(0).astype(int)

Comment: and then changed this part:       di = {'M': 10 ** 3, 'G': 10 ** 6, '0': 0}

Comment: Accept the answer if it was helpful.